# Editing list passed as argument seems to not work

Tags: java

I have this method which edits a list, but outside of the function it doesn't seem to work:

```
private void deleteOpposites(List<LinkConnection> original){
    List<LinkConnection> result = new ArrayList<LinkConnection>();

    while(original.size() > 0){
        LinkConnection l = original.remove(0); //taking first element
        for(int i=0;i<original.size();i++){
            if(original.get(i).oppositeLink(l))
                original.remove(i);
        }
        result.add(l);
    }

    original = result;
}
```

as you can see my alghoritm removes elements from the original list in order to process them. Now, the processed list is in the result local variable and I'd like for my original list to point at the new list.

Anyway, out of this function, I just get an empty list...

Comment: because `original` is declared only for this method

Comment: ?original is a paramether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the reference of an object within a method in Java. Java is not C++. Instead you can return the `result` and use it afterwards.

```
 private List<LinkConnection> deleteOpposites(List<LinkConnection> original){
 ....
 return result;
}
```

Objects in Java are passed by reference, however, the reference itself is passed by value.In other words, a copy of the reference will be passed, and this why your modifications to the reference will always be local.

Answer (score 3):

`original = result;`

This statement just assigns the reference of `result` to `original` and does not affect the `List` which is originally referred by `original`. To achieve what you want, you can do something like this.

```
original.clear(); // Clear the elements of the original list
original.addAll(result); // add all the elements from result to the original list
```

Answer (score 0):

*original* is a local variable. Changing it doesn't affect any state outside current method. Though *original* points to a list, which is mutable. So you can change it's state and all other code, which has a reference to that list will see those changes.